# How to assign a macro in a Word Document to open a PDF to specific page

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I am trying to assign a macro with commandbutton in a Word document which when clicked should open a PDF document of page 9. I trying with the below Code but not successful in solving my Problem.

I am adding the below Code in 'Module 1'.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    App_Path = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
    File_Path = "C:\Users\Desktop\USER MANUAL.pdf"
    Page_Num = 4
    Shell App_Path & " /A Page=" & Page_Num & "" & File_Path, vbMaximizedFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your paths contain spaces both paths need to be enclosed in quotes `""`

```
App_Path = """C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"""
File_Path = """C:\Users\Desktop\USER MANUAL.pdf"""
```

Also there needs to be a space between `Page_Num` and `File_Path` so replace `& "" &` with `& " " &`.

```
Shell App_Path & " /A Page=" & Page_Num & " " & File_Path, vbMaximizedFocus
```

Comment: Where i should insert the whole Code in 'This Workbook' or 'Module1'

Comment: At the position where your code was before. Also there is no `ThisWorkbook` in MS-Word. Please always try yourself before asking.

Comment: In this line a error " Shell App_Path & " /A Page=" & Page_Num & " " & File_Path, vbMaximizedFocu" no data found.

Comment: I tested it and it works. Check your paths and filenames again. You are using an old version of the Acrobat Reader. Install the current version and use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe` Also your Desktop path is missing the username and therefore is not valid. Make sure all paths are correct.

Comment: No you would need to download it first.

Comment: Ok, What could be the other ways to do? Using Hyperlinks will it be possible to open a specific page of PDF from web?

Comment: Sorry this is getting a way too off-topic here now. Your original question was already solved. Please don't ask further questions in comments that are not directly to that answer here (we cannot answer questions in comments). Don't hesitate to ask a **new** question that describes properly what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far to do it.

Comment: Ok. No Problem.